# Apache Solr Commit

Tags: solr

if I set maxTime as 10000 , ie (10 sec) then if my application stops before committing into solr, then whether this information will be lost.

whether I need to insert all these documents to solr again ??

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a whole lot of factors.

You need to check /solr/admin statistics look at Update Handlers and check to see if docsPending > 0, to see if some of your updates were processed, but not committed.